# Displaying XML in Grid View-newbie

Tags: xml, visual-studio, gridview

I am trying to do something in VisualWebDev 2008 Express that I thought would be simple, but it is not working. I want to display data from an XML file so I added the XMLDataSource to my page, pointed it to the XML file, and then added the GridView and connected it to the datasource. I am getting the following error:
GridView - GridView1There was an error rendering the control.
The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have properties or attributes to generate columns. Ensure that your data source has content.

Could someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong, 
TIA
Dean

A snippet from my XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Schools xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SchoolProjects>
            <Project>6019 - Renaissance MS - New School</Project>
            <School>Renaissance MS</School>
            <School_Address>7155 Hall Road Fairburn, GA 30213</School_Address>
            <Cluster> NS-6019200-LA-01 </Cluster>
            <Project_Type>New School</Project_Type>
            <Phase>Close-out</Phase>
            <Proj_Num>NS-6019200</Proj_Num>
            <SqFt>0.000000000000000e+000</SqFt>
            <Scope>The construction of the new Renaissance MS will be at the intersection of Jones/Hall Road, in the districts 7th &amp; 9F and Land Lots 117, 143 &amp; 146 of Fulton County, GA.  The work includes the construction of the 180,500 square foot building that will house 34 standard classrooms, 12 standard science labs, 20 special purpose classrooms, cafeteria and litchen, gymnasium, media center and administrative offices.  The site will also have multi-purpose playfields with track, softball field, tennis courts and basketball/volleyball court.</Scope>
            <Project_Manager>Terry O'Brien</Project_Manager>
            <PM_Firm>Parsons</PM_Firm>
            <AE_Firm>Stevens Wilkinson Stang Newdow</AE_Firm>
            <Contractor>Barton Malow</Contractor>
            <Start_date xsi:nil="true" />
            <End_Date xsi:nil="true" />
            <WebAddress></WebAddress>
            <Longitude>-84.62242</Longitude>
            <Latitude>33.61497</Latitude>
        </SchoolProjects>
        ...
    </Schools>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not w[ell formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). Go through the XML and remove or convert illegal characters with the appropriate [entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). An easy way to check well-formedness is to save your data in an xml file and try to open it with IE or Firefox. The browser will tell where it choked on the data.